# Come back to a specific View in SwiftUI (popToViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

Is it possible in SwiftUI to come back to a specific view? Let's say I have three views this way:

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("Navigate to View2")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("View1")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View3()) {
            Text("Navigate to View3")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("View2")
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View3!")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    View1()
  }
}
#endif
```

The navigation works back and forth:

```
View1->View2->View3
View3->View2->View1
```

Is it possible to directly come back to `View1` from the `View3`? What I'm looking for is something similar to the `UIKit`

```
func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, 
                animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?
```

Comment: Yes, and no. It requires a `NavigationView`, and a `Publisher`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view EDIT: I haven't gotten this to work yet, but that's my task this evening. For now, I'm using a `Notification` instead of a `PassthroughSubject`.

Comment: @dfd Thanks for the link. As soon as I can I'll try it on my example. And of course I'm looking forward to seeing if you can get a proper solution for this (in my opinion very important) issue.

Comment: Also interested in this!! Feels like navigation is a bit lackning in SwiftUI

Answer (score 7):

Trying to solve this issue I ended up creating an open source project called `swiftui-navigation-stack` (https://github.com/biobeats/swiftui-navigation-stack). It contains the `NavigationStackView`, a view that mimics all the navigation behaviours of the standard `NavigationView`, adding some other features (all the features are explained in the readme of the repo). To answer the question here above we can use the `NavigationStackView` this way:

Let's pretend we have to implement a navigation like this:

```
View1 (push)-> View2 (push)-> View3 (push)-> View4 (pop)-> View2
```

First of all embed your first view in a `NavigationStackView` (as you'd do with the standard `NavigationView`):

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView {
            View1()
        }
    }
}
```

Let's create these simple views to build the example:

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 1")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View2(), destinationId: "view2") {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 2")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View3()) {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 3")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View4()) {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 4")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View4: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 4")
                Spacer()
                PopView(destination: .view(withId: "view2")) {
                    Text("POP TO VIEW 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`PushView` and `PopView` let you navigate between views and, among other things, they let you specify an identifier for a view (so that you can come back to it if you need).

The following is the complete example, you can copy-paste it to xCode to try it yourself:

```
import SwiftUI
import NavigationStack

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackView {
            View1()
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 1")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View2(), destinationId: "view2") {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 2")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View3()) {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 3")
                Spacer()
                PushView(destination: View4()) {
                    Text("PUSH TO VIEW 4")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View4: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("VIEW 4")
                Spacer()
                PopView(destination: .view(withId: "view2")) {
                    Text("POP TO VIEW 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RootView()
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]