# pop to specific View in SwiftUI like we use "popToViewController"

Tags: ios, swiftui

Is it possible in SwiftUI to come back to a specific view? Like when we had controllers 
The code was this as mention below

```
let arr = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
for controller in arr!{
            if controller.isKind(of: ViewController.classForCoder()){

     self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            }
}
```

Now Let suppose I have 4 Views:-> as mentioned in the code

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                    Text("Navigate to View2")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View3()) {
            Text("Navigate to View3")
        }
    }
}

struct View3: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View4()) {
            Text("Navigate to View4")
        }
    }
}

struct View4: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("4")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pop from View4 to View2??? "Skipping View 3"
or From View3 to View 1
Likewise UIKit

Comment: Have you tried to create an Environment Object to decide which screen is gonna be show after appear or disappear?

Comment: How can you decide from @EnvironmentObject??

Comment: the same problem not getting any solution found out on every social media. As I am using NotificationCenter this is weird crack to this but this works

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57700532/1291872 I created an open source navigation stack for SwiftUI (https://github.com/biobeats/swiftui-navigation-stack), you can use it to pop to a specific view.

Comment: Thanks @superpuccio for your answer