# How Pop back to specific ViewController(UIKit) from SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have three controllers and one swiftUI view, below is the flow

**A Controller(RootController) -> B controller - > C controller -> SwiftUI view**

I am doing some operation on the SwiftUI view based on the operation need to decide to whether pop back to C controller or B. Currently I am able pop back to **C Controller and root controller**, not sure how to jump to specific (in my case B controller)controller in SwiftUI

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        })
```

I mean to say instead of this line `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` is there any method to pass view controller to pop back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Come back to a specific View in SwiftUI (popToViewController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700532/come-back-to-a-specific-view-in-swiftui-poptoviewcontroller)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pop to the Root view using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/how-can-i-pop-to-the-root-view-using-swiftui)

Comment: @SachinSingh I am able pop to root view and previous not the second one which is in-between

Comment: @Asperi , not serving my purpose

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Asperi, is possible to pass controller, check below code
.navigationBarItems(leading:Button(action: {
            if conditionSatisfy{
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}else{
popTo B controller 
}
        })

Answer (score 1):

You can make an extension for UINavigationController

```
extension UINavigationController {
  func popToViewController(ofClass: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
    if let vc = viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: ofClass) }) {
      popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
 func goBack() {
        navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass:  UIHostingController<SomeSwinftUIView>.self) // if this is a swuftUI view
}
```

or

```
 func goBack() {
    navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: SomeViewController.self)
    
    }
```

Comment: how to use UINavigationController inside SwiftUI, tried like below seems Cannot find 'navigationController' in scope
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: SomeViewController.self)
        })

Comment: just import UIKit (Personally i'm using a router/coordinator for navigation, and there I include UIKit)

Comment: This doesn't work. I used to navigate to SwiftUI view and 'viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: ofClass) })' gives me nil for a valid SwiftUI view.

Comment: @tech_human that means that your view no longer part of the navigation.

Comment: @MartaPaniti - this is what I see when I print viewControllers. Do you know if there a way to get the names of these controllers? I tried looking for UIHostingController<ContentView>.self in there and couldn't find it.

 0 : <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x1520e8200>
1 : <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x154851400>
2 : <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x155850800>

Comment: You need to write it like this: viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: ContentView.self) })

Answer (score 1):

@OhStack just import UIKit (Personally i'm using a router/coordinator for navigation, and there I include UIKit)

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIViewCoordinator {
     let navController: UINavigationController?
     
     func startView(navController: UINavigationController) {
           self.navController = navController
           let swiftUIView = SwifUIViewView(router: self)
           let hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
           navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingView, animated: true)
     }

     func goBackToSomeView() {
        navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass:  
        UIHostingController<SomeSwinftUIView>.self) 
      }
}
```