# TabView selected tab click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `TabView` with four tabs they look like this:

[image]

For example on `Search` tab user can search products (presented in a `List`) and then click on product (simple `NavigationLink`) to open up more informations (`ProductInfoView`) about that product (note `Search` tab will remain selected).

So my question is:

***if user clicks again on `Search` tab, which is still selected, how can I pop up or dismiss `ProductInfoView` and return to `Search` tab?***

Facebook has same functionality. Note also that: click on unselected tab will dismiss `ProductInfoView` and show tab I just selected but clicking again on already selected tab in this case `Search` while `ProductInfoView` is open will not do anything.

I have found similar answer here:
[SwiftUI: How to pop to Root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view)

Probably I could implement that solution but I didn't find a way how to detect user click on already selected tabItem. I know that `UITabBarController` has function which probably can do that:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {    
}
```

Maybe answer is simple but I'm still new in this field and struggling to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually simple, just keep a track of previously selected tab and when you get the current tab in the following method

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

}
```

check if currentTab == previouslySelectedTab, if yes just pop the navigation controller (currentTab.selectedViewController) to root. It should work seamlessly.

Comment: The question is tagged `SwiftUI`, this is a `UIKit` solution.