# SwiftUI: How can I pop to the root view for watchOS?

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I need to pop to the root view from a deep detail view. And while the following solution using isDetailLink and isActive works quite well for iOS, it does not work for watchOS. The isDetailLink command is unavailable in watchOS.

> 'isDetailLink' is unavailable in watchOS

```
import SwiftUI

class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var showState : Bool = false
}

struct MoreTests: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState : AppState    // injected from SceneDelegate
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: MoreView1(),
                isActive: $appState.showState,      // required to work
                label: { Text("Go to MoreView1") }
            ).isDetailLink(false)       // required to work
        }.navigationBarTitle("Root")
    }
}

struct MoreView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: MoreView2(),
            label: { Text("Go to MoreView2") }
        )
        .navigationBarTitle("MoreView1")
    }
}

struct MoreView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: MoreView3(),
            label: { Text("Go to MoreView3") }
        )
        .navigationBarTitle("MoreView2")
    }
}

struct MoreView3: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var appState : AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.appState.showState = false       // required
            }) {
                Text("Dismiss to root")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("MoreView3")
    }
}
```

The iOS solution came from *[How can I pop to the Root view using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/how-can-i-pop-to-the-root-view-using-swiftui)*.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Still an issue and wasn't solve in 7.0. We made a workaround that isn't elegant.

Comment: Works fine. Xcode 13.4 / watchOS 8.5. Project from template. Just copy-pasted above code and commented `.isDetailLink(false)`.

Comment: @Asperi you're right, confirmed. For some reason `.isDetailLink(false)` is no longer needed, at least on WatchOS. Can't believe I didn't test that myself. If you add this as an answer I can award you the bounty :)

Comment: How do you inject the AppState from SceneDelegate when initializing the root view?

Comment: Not a poptoroot, but calling the dismiss() function worked well for me! `@Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to (re)set the `id` of the `NavigationView`

Replace `AppState` with

```
class AppState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var appID = UUID()
}
```

In `MoreTests` remove the `isActive` parameter and add this modifier right before setting the `navigationBarTitle`

```
NavigationView {...

}
.id(appState.appID)
```

In `MoreView3` assign a new UUID to the `appID`

```
Button(action: {
    self.appState.appID = UUID()
}) {
    Text("Dismiss to root")
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What happens to the existing stack of NavigationLinks when the ID changes - are they kept alive by the system? Will this solution cause lots of orphaned views to build up over time, kind of like a memory leak?

Answer (score -2):

### Fixed with Xcode 13.4 / watchOS 8.5

1. Create Project from template.
2. Just copy-pasted above code
3. Commented `.isDetailLink(false)`
4. Use `MoreTests` as content of scene
5. Build & Run

Comment: Re *"the above code"*: What code are you referring to? In [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207710/swiftui-how-can-i-pop-to-the-root-view-for-watchos/72521278#72521278)? In the question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, this is not a literature forum. Read a question, read comments, read answer, and then things come together.