# WatchOS, SwiftUI pop to root view Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5, watchos-2

I need to pop to the root view from a deep detail view. Found this solution on StackOverflow [SwiftUI: How to pop to root view for WatchOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207710/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view-for-watchos). The following solution using `isDetailList` and `isActive` works quite well for iOS, it does not work for watchOS. The `isDetailList` command is unavailable in watchOS.

Below is the code that is I am using to push a view to navigation which is bounded by a condition using the tag. So we can't use both tag and **isActive** parameter into `NavigationLink` simultaneously. So looking for a solution that popup the root `viewController`.

```
Button(action: {
        nextBtnPressed()
        
    }, label: {
        Text("Next")
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
    })
    .frame(height: 35, alignment: .center)
    .background(Color.init(hex: "0A2248"))
    .cornerRadius(15)
    .disabled(false)
    .background(
        
        
        NavigationLink(
            destination: SetTimerView(shouldPopToRootView: self.$shouldPopToRootView, shower_type: self.showerType),
            tag: "true",
            selection: $movetoNextScreen,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )
        .opacity(0)
    )
}
```

Comment: When using tag instead of isActive, the selection is the bound value you use to programmatically navigate. That is, set movetoNextScreen to nil.

Comment: you mean to say that, setting movetoNextScreen nil will pop all the views upto root view controller