# SwiftUI -- Button to go to Home Screen in app

Tags: swift, mobile, swiftui

I'm trying to make a small button on the top right corner of my app that will allow the user to return to the "Home Screen" of my application. Here's what my app looks like

Launch Screen --> Home Screen --> Screen A --> Screen B --> Screen C --> ....

I basically want to be able to go from Screen A, B, C, etc to the home screen. How would I best go about doing this?

Comment: Need a little bit more clarity. How are you presenting views? Are they NavigationView? Or are you changing them on the spot? With a switch for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same button as you but It's hard to make it. Maybe the best option is creating a coordinator class, which responsability is take care of all the bindings of your app. Or even better, with an eviroment variable you can controll things easier...

However, I'm not doing like this.. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view/59662275#59662275), and what I'm doing is passing the binding for all screens (in my case make sense).