# How to dismiss two views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

I have three views in my App:
MenuViewModel -> MainActionsViewModel -> SummaryViewModel
and I would like to after click Button 'Back to menu' in SummaryViewModel back to the MenuViewModel. I've tried something like this - in `struct SummaryViewModel` added:

`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>`

and in `Button` action also added:

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

but after on click this button I go back to MainActionsViewModel, not to MenuViewModel. Is in SwiftUI possible to close 2 or more Views?

Comment: I assume you need `.isDetailLink(false)`... see, for example, here for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/59662275/12299030