# SwiftUI ToolbarItem doesn't present a View from a NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

I don't know if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong here. I've added a new button on the Navigation bar that would present a new view.

```
struct MyView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.data, id: \.name) { data in
      NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(data: data.name)) {
        Text(data.name)
      }
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {  
        NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView()) {
          Text("New Element")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is being tested on the newest iOS 14 beta (beta 6) and Xcode 12 (beta 6). As far as I know a Navigation Link presents fine the new view when on a List but in the toolbar as shown that's not the case. The button on the toolbar it's visible and active but doesn't trigger showing the new view.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`NavigationLink` should be *inside* `NavigationView`. Toolbar is not in `NavigationView`, put buttons in it.

So assuming you have somewhere in parent

```
NavigationView {
   MyView()
}
```

here is a solution:

```
struct MyView: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()
  @State private var showNew = false

  var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.data, id: \.name) { data in
      NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(data: data.name)) {
        Text(data.name)
      }
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    .background(
        NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(), isActive: $showNew) {
          EmptyView()
        }
    )
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {  
        Button("New Element") {
            self.showNew = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that, that was so helpful and quick. Thanks @Asperi! :), works like a charm!

Comment: It did work but I don't know how it's working :D

Answer (score 25):

I found using an HStack with an empty text as the first element also works, it lets the navigationLink act correctly.

```
        .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("")
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, that's weird.

Comment: That's really unusual but pure genius. How did you ever come up with this solution? Also, what do you think are the chances of this continuing to work with future Swift releases?

Comment: As of ios15, this still works

Answer (score 1):

Using Asperi solution may not work if your navigation link directs to a view with keyboard input.

After navigation link, toolbar in the new view loaded correctly but when providing input with keyboard and dismissing keyboard **all toolbar items disappears**.

The solution is to place NavigationLink not in View but in navigationBarItems, example:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Creator(),
                        isActive: $showCreator,
                        label: {
                            Text("")
                        }))
```

Comment: For me with Xcode 12.2, I found that your and @asperi's approach successfully displayed the destination, but only with asperi's would the destination pop back to this view. Perhaps a secondary issue with my code, but I also prefer using the newer ToolbarItem