# SwiftUI NavigationLink doesn't work with Spacer

Tags: swift, swiftui

I build the following View:

```
   NavigationView{
        
        VStack(spacing: 120){
            
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()){
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding()

                }
            }

            VStack{
                Image("pic1")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 160)
                    .padding()
                Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "pic2" : "pic3")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 65)
                    .padding()
                
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 250)
            
        }
        
    }
```

I need this Spacer(minLength: 250) to get the image (circle) on the top left corner. But when I do this, the Image does not work as a NavigationLink. When I delete this Spacer everything is centered and the Link works. How can I get it in the position I want and get the link work?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put something in the `toolbar` -- you might want to look into that. With a `NavigationView`, unless it's explicitly hidden, the top portion of the view is reserved for the navigation bar (and toolbar)

Comment: You need to place login button into toolbar (or into overlay above navigation view in top-right corner if you don't want toolbar) and call link programmatically. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63602455/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

use `navigationBarHidden(true)`:

```
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack(spacing: 120) {
            
            ...                

            Spacer() // no need for minHeight

        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true) // << here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have got your issue sorted
but based on your question, if I understand it properly you want to have the `Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")` in the top left corner when clicked it should navigate to the new `View`
if you want the image to be in the top right corner instead you just need to change the placement of the `ToolbarItem`
[i can't post any images yet so I included a gif link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouUd8.gif)

here is the code, i use the `ToolbarItem` and add `NavigationLink` in it
let me know if this help

Cheers,

Jono

```
    NavigationView{
        VStack(spacing: 120){
            VStack{
                Image("pic1")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 160)
                    .padding()
                Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "pic2" : "pic3")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 65)
                    .padding()
                
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 250)
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()){
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .padding()

                }
            }
        }

        
    }
```