# Image taking up lots of space in NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my View:

[image: navigationBarLeadin]

My `Image` is taking up all the space. Can I add something to the `Image` which will make it the same height as the navigation bar (and than the `Image` should be a small square)? Please no fixed frame solutions, I would expect SwiftUI can be smart enough to figure out how large the `Image` should be.

This is my code:

```
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.toolbar {
    // Directly putting a navigation link here does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602263/swiftui-toolbaritem-doesnt-present-a-view-from-a-navigationlink
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(conversation.title) {
            showConversationDetail = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Image(...)
            .resizable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to make it resizable?

Comment: @Asperi Yes, but my code doesn't reflect that, I will edit it right away

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it resizable and set the aspect ratio `contentMode`. You may or may not need to set the aspect ratio itself, depending on the image.

```
Image(...)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: The image's height is now ok, but it is still pushing away the title. The image is centered in the middle, it should be leading.

Comment: Take a look at the image itself in the Preview app. I bet you will find it has a great deal of white space on the sides. If it is very wide, it can be in the `.navigationBarLeading` position and still push everything over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this :

```
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.toolbar {
    // Directly putting a navigation link here does not work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602263/swiftui-toolbaritem-doesnt- 
present-a-view-from-a-navigationlink
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(conversation.title) {
            showConversationDetail = true
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Image(...)
            .resizable()
            // .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            .imageScale(.medium) // or you can use .small or .large accordingly
            .padding(20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I don't want fixed height/width's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In that case, you can use the .imageScale property. There is three kind of image scales available i.e. (.small, .medium, .large). You can check the above-edited answer for that. I hope it works