# How to navigate to any view inside of a NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have these 3 different views they all connect to each other through a `NavigationView`. I am trying to find a way to navigate to a page earlier in the `NavigationView` but I want the transition to seem like it is going backwards.

```
struct Testing: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:testing2()) { Text("Go to two") }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
}

struct testing2 : View {

    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: testing3()) { Text("Go to third") }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Second Page")
    }
}

struct testing3 : View {

    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            Text("Go back to first")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Third Page")
    }
}
```

I have found a solution for this using a combination of an Observable Object, an Environment variable and tags and selections on the `NavigationLink`.

Is their a simpler solution to making the navigation transition go to a specific page and if it is a view that is before the current view preform the backwards transition?

Comment: There is some good info at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334455/1630618)

Comment: I just looked through the post and one of the newer answers did something similar to what I was saying about Environment Variable. So I think I am going to stick with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

A basic workaround is to add a @Binding and pass it along. check the binding index on appear. if it's not the index presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss until it is. A more complicated way is to add a Navigator class that handles all navigation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution is to modify your third view as following:

```
struct testing3 : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Go back to first")
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Third Page")
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this allow me to navigate to any view that is inside of the `NavigationView` or just back to the top level of the `NavigationView`?

Comment: You can go to any parent view. Depending on how many times you write ` self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() `

Comment: I like the answer but I am going to continue using the Environment variable combination. Instead of having to say dismiss 3 times when I am on the 5th page to get to the 2nd page I just have to set the environment variable to the correct tag.