# SwiftUI navigation back to first screen

Tags: swiftui, navigation, back

I am trying to understand how to organize my app.
Below you can find how I want my app to be organize

Question :
How to go back from DetailView to HomeView and "re-initialize" navigation ?

[image: AppOrganize]

My Actual code to go back to First Screen

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), tag: 1, selection: $action){}
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.action = 1
            },label: {
                Text("Home")
            })
        }.padding()
```

HomeView :

```
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: ParamsView()){Text("Settings")}
```

If I navigate to :
HomeView > ParamsView > GeneralView > Tab1 > Detail > Home Button
And do it multiple times here is the result :

[image: MultipleNavigation]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view?

Comment: I am already trying to solve it with this question. But I can't find how to pass my NavigationLink :
NavigationLink(destination: getDestination(), tag: 1, selection: $action){}
to this one : 
NavigationLink(destination: getDestination(), isActive: self.$isActive, tag: 1, selection: $action ) {}
When I click on button, self.action = 1 then navigation link activate
isActive and tag/Action do not seems to be working together