# How to dismiss sheet from within NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-environment

In the following example, I have a view that shows a sheet of `ViewOne`. `ViewOne` has a `NavigationLink` to `ViewTwo`.

How can I dismiss the sheet from `ViewTwo`?

Using `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` navigates back to `ViewOne`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isShowingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet", action: {
            isShowingSheet.toggle()
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            ViewOne()
        })
    }
}

struct ViewOne: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go to ViewTwo", destination: ViewTwo())
                .isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss sheet here") {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/swiftui-how-to-pop-to-root-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may depend some on platform -- in a `NavigationView` on macOS, for example, your existing code works.

Explicitly passing a `Binding` to the original sheet state should work:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isShowingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet", action: {
            isShowingSheet.toggle()
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            ViewOne(showParentSheet: $isShowingSheet)
        })
    }
}

struct ViewOne: View {
    @Binding var showParentSheet : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go to ViewTwo", destination: ViewTwo(showParentSheet: $showParentSheet))
                //.isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @Binding var showParentSheet : Bool
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss sheet here") {
            showParentSheet = false
        }
    }
}
```