# Pop to RootView from SheetView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I [found this tutorial to pop to a RootView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926030/1720985) through a series of NavigationLinks.

I would like to do the same thing but pop to the RootView in a SheetView.

This is what the structure of my app is like:

```
struct RootController: View {
   @State var isPresented = true

   var body: Some View {
       NavigationView {
          FirstView()
       }
       .environment(\.rootPresentationMode, self.$isPresented)
   }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @Environment(\.rootPresentationMode) private var rootPresentationMode: Binding<RootPresentationMode>

   var body: Some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView,
           isActive: self.$pushNewProject) {
             EmptyView()
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .hidden()
   }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.rootPresentationMode) private var rootPresentationMode: Binding<RootPresentationMode>
    @State private var isShowingSheetView:Bool = false

   var body: Some View {
          Text(...)
          .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingEditProjectSheet){
           SheetView(showingSheetView: self.$isShowingSheetView)
        }
   }
}
```

And my SheetView (where I want to trigger the pop back to the RootView):

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.rootPresentationMode) private var rootPresentationMode

    var body: Some View {
        Text()
        .alert("Are you sure you want to delete?", isPresented: $showingDeleteAlert){
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel){
                }
                Button("Delete"){
                    print("attempt to pop")
                    self.rootPresentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
     }
}
```

after adding this extension

```
struct RootPresentationModeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<RootPresentationMode> = .constant(RootPresentationMode())
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var rootPresentationMode: Binding<RootPresentationMode> {
        get { return self[RootPresentationModeKey.self] }
        set { self[RootPresentationModeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

typealias RootPresentationMode = Bool

extension RootPresentationMode {
    
    public mutating func dismiss() {
        self.toggle()
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to pop to root from a SheetView?

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? This doesn't compile.

Comment: you are over complicating your code, a simple var passing using binding would do.

If you still want to use your complicated setup, you need to specifically pass the 
environment to a sheet. Something like: 

`SheetView(showingSheetView: self.$isShowingSheetView).environment(rootPresentationMode)
`
In `SheetView` you also need to add `@Binding var isShowingSheetView: Bool`

Comment: @workingdog even if I passed a binding var, how do I specify that I want to go back to the root from a nested child view?