# Wrong List Item Selected in NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to build out a simple navigation where you can click on items in a link and pop back to the root controller from a sheet view.  As you can see from the video below, when I tap on an item in the list, the wrong item is loaded (there's an offset between the row I click and the one that gets highlighted and loaded).

I also get the error `SwiftUI encountered an issue when pushing aNavigationLink. Please file a bug.`

Here's all my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rootIsActive:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            AllProjectView(rootIsActive: self.rootIsActive)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Root")
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .environment(\.rootPresentationMode, self.$rootIsActive)
    }
}

struct AllProjectView: View {
    @State var rootIsActive:Bool = false
    @State var projects: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(projects.indices, id: \.self){ idx in
                ProjectItem(name: self.$projects[idx], rootIsActive: self.$rootIsActive)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("All Projects")
    }
}


struct ProjectItem: View{
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var rootIsActive: Bool
    
    init(name: Binding<String>, rootIsActive: Binding<Bool>){
        self._name = name
        self._rootIsActive = rootIsActive
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ProjectView(name: self.name),
            isActive: self.$rootIsActive){
            Text(name)
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ProjectView: View {
    var name: String
    @State var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.rootPresentationMode) private var rootPresentationMode: Binding<RootPresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(name)
            Button("Show Sheet"){
                self.isShowingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet){
            Button("return to root"){
                self.isShowingSheet = false
                print("pop view")
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                print("pop root")
                self.rootPresentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Project View")
    }
}


// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926030/1720985

struct RootPresentationModeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<RootPresentationMode> = .constant(RootPresentationMode())
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var rootPresentationMode: Binding<RootPresentationMode> {
        get { return self[RootPresentationModeKey.self] }
        set { self[RootPresentationModeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

typealias RootPresentationMode = Bool

extension RootPresentationMode {
    
    public mutating func dismiss() {
        self.toggle()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `ForEach` should have an explicit id it or make `ProjectItem` identifiable. Actually `ForEach` can't differentiate between items otherwise if you don't give them a seperate id

Comment: Got it - I added an id to the ForEach but still run into the same issue.  Will update the code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `isRootActive` variable that you're using. And, it's getting repeated for each item on the list. So, as soon as *any* item on the list is tapped, the `isActive` property for *each* `NavigationLink` turns to `true`.

Beyond that, your `isRootActive` isn't actually doing anything right now, since your "Return to root" button already does this:

```
self.isShowingSheet = false
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

At that point, there's nothing more to dismiss -- it's already back at the root view.

My removing all of the root and `isActive` stuff, you get this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            AllProjectView()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Root")
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct AllProjectView: View {
    @State var projects: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(projects.indices, id: \.self){ idx in
                ProjectItem(name: self.$projects[idx])
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("All Projects")
    }
}


struct ProjectItem: View{
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ProjectView(name: self.name)
        ){
            Text(name)
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ProjectView: View {
    var name: String
    @State var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(name)
            Button("Show Sheet"){
                self.isShowingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet){
            Button("return to root"){
                self.isShowingSheet = false
                print("pop view")
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Project View")
    }
}
```

If you had an additional view in the stack, you *would* need a way to keep track of if the root were active. I've used a custom binding here that converts an optional `String` representing the project's name to a `Bool` value that gets passed down the view hierarchy:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            AllProjectView()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Root")
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct AllProjectView: View {
    @State var projects: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var activeProject : String?
    
    func activeBindingForProject(name : String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            name == activeProject
        } set: { newValue in
            activeProject = newValue ? name : nil
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(projects.indices, id: \.self){ idx in
                InterimProjectView(name: self.$projects[idx],
                                   isActive: activeBindingForProject(name: self.projects[idx]))
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("All Projects")
    }
}

struct InterimProjectView: View {
    @Binding var name : String
    @Binding var isActive : Bool
    
    var body : some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ProjectItem(name: $name, isActive: $isActive),
                       isActive: $isActive) {
            Text("Next : \(isActive ? "true" : "false")")
        }
    }
}

struct ProjectItem: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationLink(
            destination: ProjectView(name: self.name, isActive: $isActive)
        ){
            Text(name)
        }
        .isDetailLink(false)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ProjectView: View {
    var name: String
    @Binding var isActive : Bool
    @State var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(name)
            Button("Show Sheet"){
                self.isShowingSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet){
            Button("return to root"){
                self.isShowingSheet = false
                print("pop root")
                self.isActive.toggle()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Project View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?