# Where to place global NavigationPath in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm currently developing an app using `NavigationStack`. I wonder where should I put the `NavigationPath` variable so I can modify it anywhere.

I tried to put it inside the root view as a `State` variable, but it seems difficult for me to modify it inside deeply-nested views.

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Push to root") {
            // how should I access `path` from here?
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to put it as a global variable, but this may result that navigation are shared among all scene, which is not what I intended.

```swift
class Router: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = Router()
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
}

struct RootView: View {
    @ObservedObject var router = Router.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var router = Router.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Push to root") {
            router.path = []
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if someone were to provide a workable design or any suggestions.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723771/navigationstack-not-affected-by-environmentobject-changes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Binding` the same as you would to pass down write access to any other kind of `@State`. Try to stick with value types in Swift instead of falling back to familiar objects to solve problems, that'll lead to the kind of consistency bugs that Swift/SwiftUI's use of value semantics was designed to eliminate.

Comment: This turns complicated when the view hierarchy gets deeper as the binding must be passed all along the way. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You can put a binding to the path in an `EnvironmentKey`

Comment: Can you please include in your answer a working example? Your arguments are valid, but I can't seem to be able to use mutating methods like `navigationPath.append`

Answer (score 2):

Use a **global router** like below.

1. Define a Router class which conforms to `ObservableObject` protocol and has a `NavigationPath` variable.

```swift
class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()

    static let shared: Router = Router()
}
```

2. Update root view codes.

```swift
struct HomePage: View {
    @StateObject var router = Router.shared
    // 1. init router with Router.shared.
    @StateObject var router = Router.shared

    var body: some View {
        // 2. init NavigationStack with $router.path
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            Button {
                // 4. push new page
                Router.shared.path.append(category)
            } label: {
                Text("Hello world")
            }
            // 3. define navigation destinations
            .navigationDestination(for: Category.self, destination: { value in
                CategoryPage(category: value)
            })
            .navigationDestination(for: Product.self, destination: { value in
                ProductPage(product: value)
            })
    }
```

3. Update child view codes.

```swift
struct CategoryPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // push new page with Router
            Router.shared.path.append(product)
        } label: {
            Text("Hello world")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On First time I use NavigationStack and NavigationPath I was thinking as you, depend only on one global path, but I found out I cannot do it this way, because it create a lot of issues

So what I realize is every Main View need one NavigationPath
you can use your second solution but add multiple paths

```
class Router: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = Router()
    @Published var pathHome = NavigationPath()
    @Published var pathSearch = NavigationPath()
}
```

Now on main view I create StateObject and pass it to TabView using environmentObject

```
    @EnvironmentObject private var router: Router.shared

    TabView()
    .environmentObject(router)
```

inside TabView()

```
TabView {
    HomeView()
     .environmentObject(router)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Home", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")
        }

    SearchView()
     .environmentObject(router)
        .tabItem {
            Label("Search", systemImage: "tray.and.arrow.up.fill")
        }
}
```

inside HomeView

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var router: Router.shared

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.pathHome) {
           // homeView content...
        }
    }
}
```

Using this way any views inside **HomeView** will depend on `$router.pathHome`
if you have **HomeDetailsView(subview)** you can access to router without need pass it using Binding
just by adding

```
@EnvironmentObject private var router: Router.shared
```

On **SearchView** you will depend on `router.pathSearch`