# How to dismiss multiple navgation view at once

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Here I have a view A, B, and C which have the following definitions and navigation flow.
Here how can I go from view C to directly A by dismissing both B and C?

I am using this code to dismiss view C and B

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

presentationMode.wrapedValue.dismiss(

)
```

how can I dismiss at once? dismissing one by one makes the user experience quite disappointing
**ios : 13+**

```
struct A: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: B()) {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is view B")
            NavigationLink(destination: C()) {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct C: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is view C")
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into NavigationStack and NavigationPath.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you mean by that?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/how-can-i-pop-to-the-root-view-using-swiftui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Binding and change the value(isStartShow) in last structure to go to the start.
But you can't use the standard button in navigation bar, you will need to make your own button as in the example

```
struct A: View {
    @State private var isAstive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(isActive: $isAstive) {
                    B(isActive: $isAstive)
                } label: {
                    Text("Go to B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is view B")
            
            NavigationLink(destination: C(isStartShow: $isActive)) {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
        }
    } 
}

struct C: View {
    @Binding var isStartShow: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is view C")
            // your custom button:
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        isStartShow.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                            Text("Back to main")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[video example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s16Z9.gif)