# How to Pop to FirstView in multilevel NavigationLink in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In my SwiftUI project with deployment target iOS 14, I have a RootView with sub-view View1 in the below formate.
How to programmatically navigate back to RootView with View1 from View3.

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if condition1 {
                View1()
            } else {
                SomeOtherView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink to -> View2
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    NavigationLink to --> View3
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationStack iOS16 with Route, how to pop back to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079519/navigationstack-ios16-with-route-how-to-pop-back-to-root)

Comment: NavigationPath is only available in iOS 16 and above. But, as we should support iOS 14 it will not work.
Thanks.

Comment: So is `NavigationStack` (mentioned in your question). There is no built in way to do it with `NavigationView` some people have workarounds you can find on SO with `isActive`

Comment: I recommend you refer to the following answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334455/how-can-i-pop-to-the-root-view-using-swiftui