# Does the `Decimal` type have a maximum precision?

Tags: swift, foundation

I thought the whole point of the `Decimal` type was arbitrary precision arithmetic. (Or rather I thought that Decimal supported arbitrary precision as well as supporting base-10 arithmetic.)

However, an example I ran into while looking at somebody's question lead me to believe that it does have a limit. Consider this code:

```
let string = "728509129536673284379577474947011174006"

if var decimal = Decimal(string: string) {
    print("string \n'\(string) as a Decimal = \n'\(String(describing:decimal))'")
} else {
    print("error converting '\(string)' to a decimal")
}
```

That outputs

```
string 
'728509129536673284379577474947011174006 as a Decimal = 
'728509129536673284379577474947011174000'
```

It looks like the last digit gets lost. I tried various other values, and they all start showing zeros at that last digit (It looks like the low-order digit gets truncated to zero when the value contains 39 decimal digits.)

Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Please read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: "I thought the whole point of the Decimal type was arbitrary precision arithmetic." That's not correct. The point of Decimal is to store and operate on values in base 10. What you're looking for is usually called BigInt, and will likely come to swift-numerics eventually: https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/issues/5  For current work, see https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics/blob/biginteger/Sources/BigIntModule/BigInt.swift

Comment: Ok, didn't state that correctly. I thought that Decimal was supposed to provide both base 10 math AND arbitrary precision.

Comment: @Luuk, Decimal is different from Double. I am well familiar with the precision limitations on types like Double and Float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Decimal` is the bridged version of [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334455/5133585).

> An object for representing and performing arithmetic on base-10 numbers that bridges to `Decimal`; ...

Its representation is also documented in `NSDecimalNumber`:

> An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as `mantissa x 10^exponent` where `mantissa` is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and `exponent` is an integer from –128 through 127.

That is a bit inaccurate, since the [`_mantissa`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/eec4b26deee34edb7664ddd9c1222492a399d122/Sources/Foundation/Decimal.swift#L76) property does not actually store 38 decimal digits, but 128 bits.

In any case, you could say that the "maximum precision" of `Decimal` is 38 digits (or sometimes 39 digits depending on the mantissa), in the same sense that `Double` has a "maximum precision" of 15 digits (or sometimes 16 digits depending on the mantissa).

When you try to parse a number that is more precise than `Decimal` can handle, you can see that the precision is lost:

```
Decimal(string: "3402823669209384634633746074317682114551") // 40 digits
// results in    3402823669209384634633746074317682114550
```

Comment: Sweeper, thanks. That answers my question very clearly. (Voted and accepted)

Comment: I guess I knew that Decimal was bridged from NSDecimalNumber at one point. Pity the docs don't say that. The docs for NSDecimalNumber **do** say that it's bridged to Decimal, but not the other way around (ad as you quoted, the NSDecimalNumber docs give info about precision.)