# Custom back button for NavigationView's navigation bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigationview, swiftui

I want to add a custom navigation button that will look somewhat like this:

[image: desired navigation back button]

Now, I've written a custom `BackButton` view for this. When applying that view as leading navigation bar item, by doing:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: BackButton())
```

...the navigation view looks like this:

[image: current navigation back button]

I've played around with modifiers like:

```
.navigationBarItem(title: Text(""), titleDisplayMode: .automatic, hidesBackButton: true)
```

without any luck.

### Question

How can I...

1. set a view used as custom back button in the navigation bar? OR:
2. programmatically pop the view back to its parent?
   When going for this approach, I could hide the navigation bar altogether using `.navigationBarHidden(true)`

Comment: Improved version. (Swift, iOS 13 beta 4) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853828/how-to-present-view-when-clicking-on-a-button/57098885#57098885

Answer (score 157, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use this to transition *to* your view:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SampleDetails()) {}
```

Add this to the view itself:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

Then, in a button action or something, dismiss the view:

```
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

---

### Full code

From a parent, navigate using `NavigationLink`

```
 NavigationLink(destination: SampleDetails()) {}
```

In DetailsView hide `navigationBarBackButton` and set custom back button to leading `navigationBarItem`,

```
struct SampleDetails: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
            Image("ic_back") // set image here
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Go back")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            List {
                Text("sample code")
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great except presentationMode.value is now presentationMode.wrappedValue, however, this seems to disable the default swipe to go back behavior. any idea on how to enable it again?

Comment: any idea on how to add the swipe back?

Comment: Thanks , work fine, but we have to take care with the image size. Always remember `.resizable()` method for custom frame size.

Comment: fixes swipe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067845/196555

Comment: When you want to perform something .onAppear in Parent, with actual back button navigation it will work. But with your code back button, it will not work

Comment: the back button position is a bit right compared with expected,  so I have to use .offset(x, -10). Then came another problem: there's no response if you touch the back button since you have the offset now. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: @LiangWang I found wrapping the `Button` in an `HStack` with negative padding kept the touchable area the same. (If you set a background on your button, you'll see a difference compared to when you offset or pad the button itself.)

Comment: With this you can get the original sized arrow: Image(systemName: "chevron.backward").imageScale(Image.Scale.large)

Comment: This solution has been deprecated for iOS 15. Use DismissAction now https://stackoverflow.com/a/72704145/4975772

Comment: how do i make it so when you click the back button it will also refresh the home page

Comment: You can bind clouser or delegate on the back or even viewWillApper and ViewDidApper called and the previous controller. You can manage your inside

Answer (score 35):

## SwiftUI - iOS 17

It looks like you can now combine the `navigationBarBackButtonHidden` and `.toolbar` to get the effect you're trying to achieve.

### Code

```
struct Navigation_CustomBackButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Go To Detail",
                           destination: Navigation_CustomBackButton_Detail())
            .font(.title)
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Views")
        }
    }
}
// Second Screen
struct Navigation_CustomBackButton_Detail: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        }
        .navigationTitle("Detail View")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }) {
                    Label("Back", systemImage: "arrow.left.circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Example

Here is what it looks like (excerpt from the "[SwiftUI Views Mastery](https://www.bigmountainstudio.com/views)" book):
[image: Custom Back Button in SwiftUI]

Note the warning on that page: You will lose swipe-back functionality if that is important to your users.

Comment: This disables swipe to go back.

Comment: Also this doesn't work in my case when I'm using a UIKitish navigation controller, with contained SwiftUI views as vcs. In one such subview I need to hide the nav bar completely, but still implement the back button in SwiftUI and still I want to keep the swipe-to-go-back feature functioning.

Answer (score 26):

## iOS 15+

`presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` is now deprecated.

[It's replaced by `DismissAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss)

```
private struct SheetContents: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Button("Done") {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a custom back button that will use this dismiss action

```
struct CustomBackButton: View {
    let dismiss: DismissAction
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            dismiss()
        } label: {
            Image("...custom back button here")
        }
    }
}
```

then attach it to your view.

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) // Hide default button
.navigationBarItems(leading: CustomBackButton(dismiss: self.dismiss)) // Attach custom button
```

Comment: could you explain the correlation between  the two block of codes?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke The top code block is just a standalone example of how to dismiss. The bottom two show how to add a custom back button that will dismiss when tapped.

Comment: Straight to point. Correct answer!

Comment: @joshuakcockrell Doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic What do you mean? We're actively using this in production with several hundred users. Check your iOS version. Are you in a `NavigationView`/`NavigationStack`? Make a minimal example. Comment out everything in your entire app besides the main `WindowGroup` and put this in to see if it's still broken.

Answer (score 11):

Based on other answers here, this is a simplified answer for Option 2 working for me in XCode 11.0:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
           self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "gobackward").padding()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}
```

Note: To get the NavigationBar to be hidden, I also needed to set and then hide the NavigationBar in ContentView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Link").padding()
                }
            } // Main VStack
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

        } //NavigationView
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in XCode 11! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use `UIAppearance` for this:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "back-button") {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
}
```

This should be added early on in your app like `App.init`. This also preserves the native swipe back functionality.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more condensed version using principles shown in the other comments to change only the text of the button. The `chevron.left` icon can also be easily replaced with another icon.

Create your own button, then assign it using .navigationBarItems(). I found the following format most nearly approximated the default back button.

```
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var backButton : some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .font(.title2)
                Text("Cancel")
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you use `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` to hide the default button and replace it with your own!

```
        List(series, id:\.self, selection: $selection) { series in
            Text(series.SeriesLabel)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
```

Comment: This works well but is there a better way so that backButton can be shared over several views?

Answer (score 6):

I expect you want to use custom back button in all navigable screens,
so I wrote custom wrapper based on @Ashish answer.

```swift
struct NavigationItemContainer<Content>: View where Content: View {
    private let content: () -> Content
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    private var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        HStack {
            Image("back_icon") // set image here
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text("Go back")
        }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Wrap screen content in NavigationItemContainer:

**Usage:**

```swift
struct CreateAccountScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationItemContainer {
            VStack(spacing: 21) {
                AppLogoView()
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem in your CreateAccountScreenView. If you have another navigation trailing items within `CreateAccountScreenView`, then only trailing or leading navigation items. This is because you can not define navigationBarItems twice and only one works

Answer (score 6):

**Swiping is not disabled this way.**

Works for me. XCode 11.3.1

Put this in your root View

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
}
```

And this in your child View

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
    Image(systemName: "gobackward")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an excellent solution for iOS 13 and iOS 14. Working in Xcode 12.5.1

Answer (score 4):

Really simple method. Only two lines code

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    @State var showSecondView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(),isActive : self.$showSecondView){
            Text("Push to Second View")
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView : View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body : some View {    
        Button(action:{ self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }){
            Text("Go Back")    
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All of the solutions I see here seem to disable swipe to go back functionality to navigate to the previous page, so sharing a solution I found that maintains that functionality. You can make an extension of your root view and override your navigation style and call the function in the view initializer.

**Sample View**

```
struct SampleRootView: View {

    init() {
        overrideNavigationAppearance()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

**Extension**

```
extension SampleRootView {
   func overrideNavigationAppearance() {
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        let barAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        barAppearace.tintColor = *desired UIColor for icon*
        barAppearace.barTintColor = *desired UIColor for icon*

        navigationBarAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(*desired UIImage for custom icon*, transitionMaskImage: *desired UIImage for custom icon*)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
   }
}
```

The only downfall to this approach is I haven't found a way to remove/change the text associated with the custom back button.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for iPhone. However, for iPad it won't work because of the splitView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavigationBackButton: View {
  var title: Text?
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      VStack {
        ZStack {
          HStack {
            Button(action: {
              self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
              Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
              title
            }
            Spacer()
          }
        }
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .zIndex(1)
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
}

struct NavigationBackButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NavigationBackButton()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 14+ it's actually very easy using `presentationMode` variable

In this example `NewItemView` will get dismissed on `addItem` completion:

```
struct NewItemView: View {
    @State private var itemDescription:String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $itemDescription)
        }.onTapGesture {
            hideKeyboard()
        }.toolbar {
            
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem){
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationTitle("Add Question")
        
    }
    private func addItem() {
        // Add save logic
        // ...
        
        // Dismiss on complete
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
    private func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct NewItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewItemView()
    }
}
```

In case you need the parent (Main) view:

```
struct SampleMainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \DbQuestion.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("This is item detail page")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Item at \(item.id)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                        // Creates a button on toolbar
                        NavigationLink {
                            // New Item Page
                            NewItemView()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add item")
                        }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Main Screen")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://ryanashcraft.me/swiftui-programmatic-navigation/

It does work, and it may lay the foundation for a state machine to control what is showing, but it is not a simple as it was before.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    var onDismiss: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(
            "Here are details. Tap to go back.",
            action: self.onDismiss
        )
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var link: NavigationDestinationLink<DetailView>
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

    init() {
        let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
        self.link = NavigationDestinationLink(
            DetailView(onDismiss: { publisher.send() }),
            isDetail: false
        )
        self.publisher = publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("I am root. Tap for more details.", action: {
                self.link.presented?.value = true
            })
        }
            .onReceive(publisher, perform: { _ in
                self.link.presented?.value = false
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            RootView()
        }
    }
}

If you want to hide the button then you can replace the DetailView with this:

struct LocalDetailView: View {
    var onDismiss: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(
            "Here are details. Tap to go back.",
            action: self.onDismiss
        )
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text(""))
    }
}
```

Comment: You know you can edit your answers? Don't post a new one but click the little [*edit* button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57008452/edit) at the bottom of your answer. Then, delete this one.

Comment: Improved version. (Swift, iOS 13 beta 4)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56853828/how-to-present-view-when-clicking-on-a-button/57098885#57098885

Comment: Interesting that I get blasted for posting a link to the point of getting my account severely limited, but this last answer gets through perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just write this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

        }.onAppear() {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it kinda "works" but the new back button image is not aligned correctly. The code might need some adjustments. Also, maybe it might be better to put it inside the init() {}?