# SwiftUI: How to present view when clicking on a button?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to make an app using Apple's **SwiftUI** and I need to have two buttons that present two different views in a single `List` row.

I use **Xcode beta 7** and **MacOS Catalina beta 7**. I've tried to add a `Button` that present the view but, I couldn't click it and when I tried on a simple `Button` outside the `List` and clicked it, the `AddList()` view didn't appear. I've also tried adding a `navigationButton` inside `navigationButton` but it didn't work too. Adding a `tapAction` doesn't work too when you click on it, the view still does not appear

```
NavigationView {
            List(0..<5) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentOfList()) {
                    Text("hello") // dummy text
                    Spacer()
                    Text("edit")
                        .tapAction {
                            AddList() // This is the view I want to present
                    }
                }
                }.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: AddList(), label: { // doesn't work within navigationBarItems
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }))
        }
```

I expect the `AddList()` view to appear but in the two cases, it doesn't.

Comment: What I mean by "present" is replace the default view by the AddList() view. Like what you usually do with a NavigationButton. So as you say, my gaol is to navigate to a different interface. As I wrote, I've also tried adding a navigationButton inside navigationButton but it didn't work. My question may not be clear, what I want to do is, when clicking on the 'edit' Button, navigate to a different interface (the AddList() interface) and when I click somewhere else in my row, to navigate to the 'ContentOfList()' interface.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea on how to fix the issue about adding a navigationButton inside navigationButton ?

Comment: @matt it is actually possible, using **DynamicNavigationDestinationLink**. I posted my answer below.

Comment: I think they finally got it right in Beta 5. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much improved version (SwiftUI, iOS 13 beta 7)

The same solution works for dismissing Modals presented with the .sheet modifier.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            "Here is Detail View. Tap to go back.",
            action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }
        )
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView())
            { Text("I am Root. Tap for Detail View.") }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            RootView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually it is quite great. Do you know if there is any way to disable the blue background (on the pictures) of the NavigationLink ?

Comment: @ChristophePrat  `.renderingMode` on the image

Answer (score 5):

***Update: The NavigationButton was very short lived. In beta3 it is already deprecated. I am updating the code to use its replacement: NavigationLink***.

You can present a view from all three places. Here's how:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TopView().navigationBarTitle(Text("Top View"))
        }
    }
}

struct TopView: View {
    @State private var viewTypeA = true

    let detailViewA = DynamicNavigationDestinationLink(id: \String.self) { data in
            ListA(passedData: data)
    }

    let detailViewB = DynamicNavigationDestinationLink(id: \String.self) { data in
            ListB(passedData: data)
    }

    var body: some View {
            List(0..<5) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ListC(passedData: "FROM ROW #\(item)")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Row #\(item)")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("edit")
                            .tapAction {
                                self.detailViewA.presentedData?.value = "FROM TAP ACTION Row #\(item)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                            self.detailViewB.presentedData?.value = "FROM PLUS CIRCLE"
            }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }))
    }
}

struct ListA: View {
    let passedData: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("VIEW A")
            Text(passedData)
        }
    }
}

struct ListB: View {
    let passedData: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("VIEW B")
            Text(passedData)
        }
    }
}

struct ListC: View {
    let passedData: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("VIEW C")
            Text(passedData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to include animated gif.

Comment: That’s clever but you are not navigating to three different views. You are navigating to the same view with three different data strings.

Comment: @matt It's a generic example. You can always extend it to use different views for each. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @kontiki actually, I don't understand how you can move to three different views using DynamicNavigationDestinationLink

Comment: Hi @ChristophePrat, I updated the code to navigate to three different views, depending where the user taps (row, edit button or plus button).

Comment: I found out myself: you need to have a top view containing a view.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't around to reply sooner. Yes, you are right, the view where the NavigationView is, will have `presentedData` as nil, and so it won't work there. You need to encapsulate as I did with TopView. Not sure if it's a bug or intended.

Answer (score 1):

improved version. (Swift, iOS 13 beta 4)

```
class NavigationModel : BindableObject {
    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var presentedData: String? {
        didSet {
            willChange.send()
        }
    }
    func dismiss() { if presentedData != nil {
        presentedData = nil
    } }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MasterView()
        }.environmentObject(NavigationModel())
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject
    var navigationModel: NavigationModel
    var destinationLink = DynamicNavigationDestinationLink<String, String, DetailView>(id: \.self) { data in DetailView(data: data) }

    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10) { index in
            Button("I am root. Tap for more details of #\(index).") {
                self.navigationModel.presentedData = "#\(index)"
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Master")
        .onReceive(navigationModel.willChange) {
            self.destinationLink.presentedData?.value = self.navigationModel.presentedData
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var model: NavigationModel

    let data: String

    var body: some View {
        Button("Here are details of \(data). Tap to go back.") {
            self.model.dismiss()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail \(data)")
    }
}

struct Empty : Hashable {
}


#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```