# Remove back button text from navigationbar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui

I've recently started working in SwiftUI, came to the conclusion that working with navigation isn't really great yet. What I'm trying to achieve is the following. I finally managed to get rid of the translucent background without making the application crash, but now I ran into the next issue. How can I get rid of the "back" text inside the navbaritem?

[image]

I achieved the view above by setting the default appearance in the `SceneDelegate.swift` file like this.

```
let newNavAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
newNavAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
newNavAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(UIImage(named: "backButton"), transitionMaskImage: UIImage(named: "backButton"))
newNavAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
    .font: UIFont(name: GTWalsheim.bold.name, size: 18)!,
    .backgroundColor: UIColor.white

]

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = newNavAppearance
```

One possible way that I could achieve this is by overriding the navigation bar items, however this has one downside ([SwiftUI Custom Back Button Text for NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906365/swiftui-custom-back-button-text-for-navigationview)) as the creator of this issue already said, the back gesture stops working after you override the navigation bar items. With that I'm also wondering how I could set the foregroundColor of the back button. It now has the default blue color, however I'd like to overwrite this with another color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I actually ended up with the following solution that actually works. I am overwriting the navigation bar items like so

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
    Image("backButton")
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
)
```

The only issue with this was that the back gesture wasn't working so that was solved by actually extending the `UINavigationController`

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Now it's looking exactly the way I want it, the solution is kinda hacky... but it works for now, hopefully SwiftUI will mature a little bit so this can be done easier.

Comment: Does't this give you duplicate navigation and back button on swipe back ? for me it was the case. So I ended up increasing navigation title width using toolbar.

Answer (score 57):

Piggy-backing on the solution @Pitchbloas offered, this method just involves setting the `backButtonDisplayMode` property to `.minimal`:

```
extension UINavigationController {

  open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    navigationBar.topItem?.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
  }

}
```

Comment: I didnt know about 'backButtonDisplayMode', thanks!

Comment: This is a great option! Just a note to others that it requires iOS 14+.

Comment: Found this to be a good solution, but should call `super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()` prior to setting the button display mode

Comment: This will change the behaviour of every back button in your app. If that is what you want, this is a great and simple solution, otherwise look at the other answers...

Answer (score 40):

It's actually really easy. The following solution is the fastest and cleanest i made.

Put this at the bottom of your SceneDelegate for example.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    // Remove back button text 
    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

This will remove the back button text from every NavigationView (UINavigationController) in your app.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for a simple solution like this one for days.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

I have found a straightforward approach to remove the back button text using SwiftUI only, and keeping the original chevron.

A drag gesture is added to mimic the classic navigation back button
when user wants to go back by swiping right. Following this, an extension of `View` is created to create a SwiftUI like modifier.

This is how to use it in code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      // Your main view code here with a ZStack to have the
      // gesture on all the view.
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonTitleHidden()
  }
}
```

This is how to create the `navigationBarBackButtonTitleHidden()` modifier:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {

  func navigationBarBackButtonTitleHidden() -> some View {
    self.modifier(NavigationBarBackButtonTitleHiddenModifier())
  }
}

struct NavigationBarBackButtonTitleHiddenModifier: ViewModifier {

  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

  @ViewBuilder @MainActor func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .navigationBarItems(
        leading: Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
          Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
          .imageScale(.large) })
      .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Start of the gesture to dismiss the navigation
      .gesture(
        DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .local)
          .onEnded { value in
            if value.translation.width > .zero
                && value.translation.height > -30
                && value.translation.height < 30 {
              dismiss()
            }
          }
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I will mention that presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss has been a headache in a project, sometimes causing app crashes in specific instances.

Comment: Thanks. This can be refactored into a custom modifier: https://gist.github.com/janodev/9d765a827ba3af407e70cc380cffeb80

Comment: @Jano I have updated the code following your suggestion

Comment: No one should be hiding the baked in back button to customize it with a left bar button item. This strips out an absurd amount of system functionality and features from ADA to basic swipe actions.

Answer (score 8):

you can use .toolbarRole(.editor)

Comment: most simple and clean way among these answers

Comment: Though this is  ios 16+ only still this is the best one

Answer (score 6):

If you want to:

- Do it globally
- Keep the standard back button (along with custom behaviours like an ability to navigate a few screens back on a long press)
- Avoid introducing any third party frameworks

You can do it by setting the back button text color to Clear Color via appearance:

```
let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
backButtonAppearance.focused.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
backButtonAppearance.disabled.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
backButtonAppearance.highlighted.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

navigationBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance

//Not sure you'll need both of these, but feel free to adjust to your needs.
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

You can do it once when the app starts and forget about it.

A potential downside (depending on your preferences) is that the transition to the clear color is animated as the title of the current window slides to the left as you move to a different one.

You can also experiment with different text attributes.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) framework, you can easily gain access to the underlying navigation item and set the `backButtonDisplayMode` to minimal.

Here’s how you might use that in the view that was pushed

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Your body here")
        .introspectNavigationController { navController in
            navController.navigationBar.topItem?.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard *Back* button title is taken from navigation bar title of previous screen.

It is possible the following approach to get needed effect:

[image: demo]

```
struct TestBackButtonTitle: View {
    @State private var hasTitle = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go", destination:
                Text("Details")
                    .onAppear {
                        self.hasTitle = false
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        self.hasTitle = true
                    }
            )
            .navigationBarTitle(self.hasTitle ? "Master" : "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright yes this is a possible solution, but it's really nasty, if I'd have to do that on EVERY screen it would be kind of annoying and hacky. I'm looking for a way to globally disable this text.

Answer (score 2):

Works on iOS 16

Solutions above didn't work for me. I wanted to make changes specific to view without any global (appearance or extension) and with minimal boilerplate code.

`Since you can update NavigationItem inside the init of the View. You can solve this in 2 steps:`

1. Get visible View Controller.

```
// Get Visible ViewController
extension UIApplication {
    
    static var visibleVC: UIViewController? {
        var currentVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.rootViewController
        while let presentedVC = currentVC?.presentedViewController {
            if let navVC = (presentedVC as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.last {
                currentVC = navVC
            } else if let tabVC = (presentedVC as? UITabBarController)?.selectedViewController {
                currentVC = tabVC
            } else {
                currentVC = presentedVC
            }
        }
        return currentVC
    }
    
}
```

2. Update NavigationItem inside init of the View.

```
struct YourView: View {
    
    init(hideBackLabel: Bool = true) {
        if hideBackLabel {
            // iOS 14+
            UIApplication.visibleVC?.navigationItem.backButtonDisplayMode = .minimal
            
            // iOS 13-
            let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            UIApplication.visibleVC?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the arrow image and hide the text of the native back button use the SwiftUI modifier `navigationTitle` and pass an empty string like this:

```
.navigationTitle("")
```

If you still need to display a title on your view, add a toolbar item with `principal` placement. That's the Apple recommended way: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement/principal

**Important:** Because the native back button displays the title of the previous screen, **use that modifier on the pushing view, not on the pushed one.**

**NB**: the modifier is available on iOS 14+

Answer (score 0):

custom navigationBarItems and self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() worked but you are not allow to perform swiping back

You can either add the following code to make the swipe back again

```
//perform gesture go back
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

but the problem is, sometimes it will make your app crashed when you swipe half the screen and then cancel.

I would suggest the other way to remove the "Back" text.
Adding the isActive state to monitor whether the current screen is active or not. :)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            NavigationLink(
                "Next",
                destination: Text("Second Page").navigationBarTitle("Second"),
                isActive: $isActive
            )
                .navigationBarTitle(!isActive ? "Title" : "", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On iOS 15.2 this (the second fix using the $isActive binding) works to disable the back button text but it causes a random item to be selected on navigation and the debug console shows the error "SwiftUI encountered an issue when pushing aNavigationLink. Please file a bug."

Answer (score 0):

I am accomplishing this by changing the title of the master screen before pushing the detail screen and then setting it back when it re-appears. The only caveat is when you go back to the master screen the title's re-appearance is a little noticeable.

Summary:

- on master view add state var (e.g. isDetailShowing) to store if detail screen is showing or not
- on master view use the navigationTitle modifier to set the title based on the current value of isDetailShowing
- on master view use onAppear modifier to set the value of isDetailShowing to false
- on the NavigationLink in master screen use the simultaneousGesture modifier to set the isDetailShowing to true

  ```
  struct MasterView: View {
    @State var isDetailShowing = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 20)
            Text("Master Screen")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 20)

            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Go to detail screen")
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded() {
                isDetailShowing = true
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle(isDetailShowing ? "" : "Master Screen Title")
        .onAppear() {
            isDetailShowing = false
        }
    }
  }

  struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the detail screen")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Detail Screen Title")
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a detailed answer to agree and append to the appearance proxy responses. DO NOT hide the system back button and replace it with a left bar button item. This is the literal worst offending way to fake a back button and ultimately strips your app of a ton of system baked in behaviors.

```
public extension View {
func navigationBarAppearance(_ appearance: UINavigationBarAppearance) -> some View {
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationBarAppearance.compactAppearance = appearance
    navigationBarAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    return self
}
```

}

```
public extension UINavigationBarAppearance {
static var appBarAppearance: UINavigationBarAppearance {
    let navigationItemAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance.default
    let textColor = UIColor.myColor
    let font = UIFont.myFont
    var titleTextAttributes = navigationItemAppearance.titleTextAttributes
    var largeTitleTextAttributes = navigationItemAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes
    titleTextAttributes[.font] = font
    largeTitleTextAttributes[.foregroundColor] = textColor
    navigationItemAppearance.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
    navigationItemAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = largeTitleTextAttributes

    let backItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    backItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: textColor,
        .font: font
    ]

    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = textColor
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .myColor

    let backButtonBackgroundImage = myChevronImage
    navigationItemAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(backButtonBackgroundImage, transitionMaskImage: backButtonBackgroundImage)
    let backButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0)]
    navigationItemAppearance.backButtonAppearance = backButtonAppearance
    return navigationItemAppearance
}
```

}

```
ContentView()
   .navigationBarAppearance(.appBarAppearance)
```

Have at it

Answer (score -3):

Why not use Custom BackButton with Default Back Button Hidden

You could use Any Design You Prefer !

Works on iOS 16

**First View**

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(){
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                Text("Navigate")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Second View**

```
struct View2: View {
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                HStack(alignment:.center){
//Any Design You Like
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                           .font(.title)
                           .foregroundColor(.blue)
                           .onTapGesture {                          
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                           }
                           .padding()
                   Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
}
```