# swiftUI backButtonDisplayMode

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am wondering how we can implement `backButtonDisplayMode` in SwiftUI or to achieve similar result. So there is no back button text or navigation title, but I want to have custom text in the history stack menu called out by long press on the back button, which is like  having `backButtonTitle` but with `.minimal` display mode

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528430/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi the back button text is removed already, maybe the question should be ' how to have custom text in the history stack menu with no back button text or navigation title'