# SwiftUI - navigationBarBackButtonHidden - swipe back gesture?

Tags: swiftui

if I set a custom Back Button (which everyone wants, hiding the ugly text ;-) ) and using .navigationBarBackButtonHidden, the standard Swipe Back gesture on the navigation controller does not work. Is there a way to get this back and having a custom back button?

For Example:

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: DummyViewer())
     {
       Text("Go to next view"
    } 
 }
```

```
struct DummyViewer: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!").navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                    Text("Custom go back")
                }
        )
    }
}
```

If I do so, I cannot swipe back to the previous view, seems the gesture is then disabled... How to get it back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide navigation bar without losing swipe back gesture in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921239/hide-navigation-bar-without-losing-swipe-back-gesture-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 106):

Nothing I found about creating a custom NavigationView worked but I found that by extending `UINavigationController` I was able to have a custom back button and the swipe back gesture.

```swift
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: This still works as of now (Xcode 11.4.1 on iOS 13.2)

Comment: Still works on iOS 14.2. What a powerful spell!

Comment: Still works in 14.5, thx! I wonder what the implications of this are because this is being applied to all navigation controls globally

Comment: Works in iOS 15 Developer Beta 1

Comment: But how to do some clean up after user swipes back?

Comment: This still works in iOS 15.4 and Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: where do I put it? I couldn't make it work on ios15

Comment: That's absolutely the way to go also on Xcode14 / iOS16.2! Awesome!

Comment: Still works in Xcode 14.2. Improved answers below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76154592/3991269

Comment: Does not work in iOS 17 when returning to root view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226166/how-to-fix-uinavigationcontroller-extension-which-breaks-swiftui-navigation-in-i

Answer (score 27):

I would like to integrate the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067845/9790551) given by Nick Bellucci to make the code also works in other circumstances, e.g. when the child view of the NavigationView is a ScrollView, or a View that is listening for Drag gestures.

```swift
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    } 

    // To make it works also with ScrollView
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice hint for making it works with scroll view.

Comment: where do I put it? I couldn't make it work on ios15

Comment: @tcgumus you can put it in any Swift file inside the project

Comment: This worked perfectly since my entire view is a page style tabview. Had to make a few tweaks but it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Crashes in iOS17 if going to root.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226166/how-to-fix-uinavigationcontroller-extension-which-breaks-swiftui-navigation-in-i

Answer (score 4):

I've just created a hack which will not animate view but it works

```
extension View {
    func onBackSwipe(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onEnded({ value in
                    if value.startLocation.x < 50 && value.translation.width > 80 {
                        action()
                    }
                })
        )
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.red
        }
        .onBackSwipe {
            self.dismiss()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works for me for the version 16.4 . Thank you very much.

Comment: Crashes in iOS17 if going to root.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226166/how-to-fix-uinavigationcontroller-extension-which-breaks-swiftui-navigation-in-i

Comment: view Animation is major, which is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to integrate the answer given by Niccolò Fontana who integrate the answer given by Nick Bellucci to make the code even better.

Niccolò Fontana makes it also works when the child view of the NavigationView is a ScrollView, or a View that is listening for Drag gestures.

But in that case you will simultaneously scroll and swipe. That fills  annoying. And if you want original behavior, you should use that snippet:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    } 

    // To make it works also with ScrollView
    // public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    //     true
    // }

    // To make it works also with ScrollView but not simultaneously 
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just wanna add this in your code and you can easily use the swipe back gesture with a custom back button or navigation bar hidden.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice easy solution, works for this particular question. But does not work with horizontal scrollview inside, which scrolling gesture has a higher priority, so swipe to go back does not work. Though, correct if there is no horizontal scroll view (TabView in my case).

Comment: Yes you are right, it won't work when there is horizontal scrollview as it's Z-index would be greater than the main screen. What you can do is that have small margin on left and right and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the people have mentioned an issue with iOS17 where the app freezes after swiping back once... I think I found a solution by slightly modifying @Nick's answer:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(
        _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
        shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
    ) -> Bool {
        return gestureRecognizer.isEqual(self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is `nil`, this option does not work.

Comment: @bodich that is odd. I'm definitely using this in an iOS17 App that uses NavigationStack, and I am able to completely customize the back button while keeping the "swipe to go back" functionality.

Comment: I can customize and have swipe-back too, but if just return true in this method. `self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is `nil`. Also iOS 17, but don’t think any difference here.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the title to an empty `string`. So back bar button title will be empty:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Here you are")) {

                Text("Next").navigationBarTitle("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>You can set the title `onAppear` or `onDisappear` if you need to.</sub>

Comment: Hi, I added some more information. It is about the Back Button and the Swipe gesture which it causes - or not.

Answer (score -2):

If it's still actual, [here I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944756/9982386), how to set custom back button and save swipe back gesture.