# How to make Navigation Bar back button always say back if the previous view has no title?

Tags: swiftui

E.g. if you navigate from View A to View B, View B will typically display a back button on the left side of the navigation bar that says "< View A" (assuming that View A's title is `"View A"`).

When I don't have a title in View A, the back button in view B is simply `"<"` which is as expected, because view A has no title.

Now is there a way to make it so that if there is no title in the previous view, it should always say `"< Back"`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own back button which can be individualized:

Put this at the top of your view:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}) {
    Text("< Back")
    }
}
```

And at at the end of your Stack in that View:

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)    
.navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Is there a way to make it like native, i.e. the "<" uses the actual back icon instead?

Comment: Use Image(systemName: "chevron.left") before Text(" Back").

Comment: @pizzae, as far as I remember this approach disables swipe-to-back, just in case.

Comment: @Asperi Yep I just encountered that problem and managed to solve it with the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067845/6280334