# iOS SwiftUI - NavigationView NavigationLink: Close view with custom Button

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm new to iOS development and think it's awesome, BUT I absolutely H A T E everything about NavigationView/NavigationLink, even in Android it's very hard to find such idiocy!

In ContentView I have:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Login().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), label: {
    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 32)
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
})
```

And Login():

```
struct Login: View {
    @AppStorage("userid") var userid: Int = 0

    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack{
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    // Close the view!!???
 
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .resizable()
                        
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
                }
                .padding(.top, 12.0)
                .padding(.trailing, 16.0)
            }
                         
            Spacer()
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

How can I just close the View clicking on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. Take a look at [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself) for more information. Here is how you would use it:

```swift
struct Login: View {
    @AppStorage("userid") var userid: Int = 0
//Doesn't require anything to be passed in.
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack{
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
//Part where view is dismissed
                   presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
 
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .resizable()
                        
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
                }
                .padding(.top, 12.0)
                .padding(.trailing, 16.0)
            }
                         
            Spacer()
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

You would still call this the same way, with a `NavigationLink` like in the original question above.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594164/18457910) for more info on dismissing. Also, note that this will disable the default swipe-back behavior, if you want to re-enable it, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067845/18457910).