# Show NavigationLink based on condition and having value edited inside the destination

Tags: swiftui

I have a ForEach loop for my `StudentStore` and only want to display them in my list if the `isFavorite` field is true.

The problem is when I edit the value of isFavorite inside `SecondView`, it goes back to `ContentView` because of the `if` statement inside `ContentView`.

I want the list to update when I get back to `ContentView` rather than updating it immediately causing it to go back to the original page.

[image]

When I was looking for a solution I came upon this:

> Read this entire thread thinking you were asking if you could make a NavigationView conditionally hidden and thought, “That sounds like a mess...”
>   Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/e2wn09/make_navigationlink_conditional_based_on_bool/

Can someone also how to solve this problem and why conditionally hiding a `NavigationView` is a bad idea?

Model

```
import SwiftUI

struct StudentItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool

    init(name: String, isFavorite: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
    }
}

class StudentStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var StudentStore: [StudentItem]

    init(StudentStore: [StudentItem]){
        self.StudentStore = StudentStore
    }
}
```

Main view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var studentStore = StudentStore(StudentStore: [StudentItem(name: "Stephen", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "Jay", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "Isaac", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "Talha", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "John", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "Matt", isFavorite: true),
                                                                   StudentItem(name: "Leo", isFavorite: true)])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(studentStore.StudentStore.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Group {
                        if self.studentStore.StudentStore[index].isFavorite == true {
                            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(student: self.$studentStore.StudentStore[index])) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(self.studentStore.StudentStore[index].name)
                                    Image(systemName: self.studentStore.StudentStore[index].isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sub view

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var student: StudentItem

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.student.isFavorite.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: student.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem makes sense, it's a Binded value.  The Navigation to that person `SecondView` technically no longer exists according to the Binding.

You could create a localized `State` for `SecondView`, set your Image and Button to work that that property, and then use `onDisappear` to update the `StudentItem` as you Navigate back.

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var student: StudentItem
    @State var isFavorite: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isFavorite.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: self.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
        }.onDisappear {
            self.student.isFavorite = self.isFavorite
        }
    }
}
```

The above will work with the rest of your code.

As for not using an `if` statement, I kind of get it.  For me, I would want to iterate through the values I know I want to include.  Not saying this is perfect, but you could filter the list before you go in, and then summon the Bindable reference to the `StudentItem` to pass into `SecondView`. Be sure to make `StudentItem` `Hashable` for this to work:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(studentStore.StudentStore.filter({$0.isFavorite == true}), id: \.self) { student in
                    Group {
                        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(student: self.$studentStore.StudentStore[self.studentStore.StudentStore.firstIndex(of: student)!])) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(student.name)
                                    Image(systemName: student.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This results in a more desirable result but I would prefer the transition to happen before the `list` is visible.

Comment: I hear ya.  Another solution is making your own Back Button, similar to the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui). This way, you can specifically update the Bindable object before calling for a dismiss.  Something to be mindful of is that I'm not sure if you'll still want to call a dismiss after updating the value to false, since that may "auto-dismiss" like in the root issue, lol.