# How to make infinite transitions in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to swift, I work in SwiftUI, I want to learn how to make such transitions:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uHM7cA5N0pju6x1Pqfw3u7JWKjBU-MRP/view?usp=sharing

And what tool can be used to make endless transitions on different views

P. s. infinite transition - a constant transition like on a video, without a dead end

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you just asking how to do the vertical transition? Besides that, it just looks like buttons which transition from view to view.

Comment: @jnpdx, Animations are not needed yet. For now, I just need transitions to different views.
I tried navigation link, but the standard back arrow appears in it, and I want to make a custom one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what you need!
And can you tell me if navigation link is the best tool for transitions?

Comment: Yes, NavigationLink is the most common way to move from view to view.