Can I set the color of the back button conditionally, based on the View?
I've seen several questions about how to set the color of the Back button in a NavigationStack/NavigationView by using .accentColor or .tint. However, none of them address my issue.
I have a HomeView.Swift that looks like this:
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var categories: [Category]
    @State var isAddingNewCateogry = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List($categories) { $category in
                NavigationLink(destination: CategoryView(category: $category)) {
                        CategoryCard(category: category)
                    }
                    .listRowBackground(category.theme.mainColor)
            }
            .listRowSpacing(12)
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: { isAddingNewCateogry = true }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Essentially, what I want to do, is when I navigate to one of the CategoryViews. The format of the page has a Card that covers the top 1/3 of the screen with a .background(category.theme.mainColor)
Sometimes, that mainColor conflicts with the default blue accent color, so I'd like to have the Back button default to category.theme.accentColor. I can't set it in the HomeView, because it's contingent on the theme of the category being passed to the CategoryView.
Is there a way that I can set this within the CategoryView so that it can be conditional based on the category.theme?

you could try replacing the default back button with your own, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui/  and give it the color you want. PS, there is an answer using ios17.
