Back chevron's color, and alternate text for "Back", when using SwiftUI and UIKit mix using hostingController
I tried everything, but I couldn't change the color of the chevron here. I have a UIKit ViewController which in turn is instantiating a SwiftUI view, which in turn creates and displays 3 other SwiftUI views. Clicking on any one of these 3 links gets me to that SwiftUI view just fine. I can also change the color of the text "Back" but I am not able to change the text itself, nor the color of the chevron. How can I do that? This is HomeVC.swift:
    import UIKit
    import SwiftUI
    
    class HomeVC: GosViewController {
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let vju = HomeView(parentVc: self)
            let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: vju)
            addChild(hostingController)
            hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
    
            hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
            
            let backButton = UIButton()
            backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .highlighted )
            backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .normal )
            backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .focused )
            backButton.setTitle(" Backa", for: .normal)
            backButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            backButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME, size: vcLinkSize)
            backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleBackButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            
            let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
            hostingController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
            hostingController.navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            
            let ta:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                .foregroundColor: GOS_LINK_COLOR,
                .strokeColor: GOS_LINK_COLOR,
                .font : UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME,
                               size: vcLinkSize)!
            ]
            
            
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = ta
            appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = ta
            
            // Ensure back button chevron is black
            appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ta
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
            
            hostingController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
            hostingController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
            hostingController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButtonItem, animated: true)
            hostingController.navigationController?.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButtonItem, animated: true)
            hostingController.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance
            hostingController.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
            
            
            return
                
        }
        
        
        @objc func handleBackButtonTapped() {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    
    }

this is HomeView.swift:
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    let firstButtonMsg = "Profile"
    let secondButtonMsg = "Latest matches"
    let thirdButtonMsg = "Top List"
    let fourthButtonMsg = "Tournaments"
    var parentVc: GosViewController?
    
    @State private var displayTestButtonForToast = false
    
    init(parentVc: GosViewController? = nil, displayTestButtonForToast: Bool = false) {
        self.parentVc = parentVc
        self.displayTestButtonForToast = displayTestButtonForToast
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance()
            .largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME, size: vcLinkSize)!]
        
        
        let ta:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: GOS_LINK_COLOR,
            .font : UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME,
                           size: vcLinkSize)!
        ]
        
        
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = ta
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = ta
        
        appearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ta
        
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = ta
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        
        
        let backButton = UIButton()
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .normal)
        backButton.setTitle(" Backb", for: .normal)
        backButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        backButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME, size: vcLinkSize)
        
        
        let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        
        let uni: UINavigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "farog")
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
        
        
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                if displayTestButtonForToast {
                    ToastTestBattery()
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    
                    ProfileView(pvc: parentVc!)
                        .navigationTitle(
                            getLoggedInUserIdentity()
                        )
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        .font(Font.custom(GOS_FONT_NAME, size: 25).bold())
                        
                    
                } label: {
                    MenuText(firstButtonMsg)
                }
                
                
                NavigationLink {
                    LatestMatchesView()
                } label: {
                    MenuText(secondButtonMsg)
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    TopListView()
                } label: {
                    MenuText(thirdButtonMsg)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: LogOutButtonView())
            
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}

and this is ProfileView.swift:
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {

    
    var parentVc: GosViewController?
    
    init(pvc: GosViewController?) {
        parentVc = pvc
        
        
        let ta:[NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: GOS_LINK_COLOR,
            .font : UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME,
                           size: vcLinkSize)!
        ]
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = ta
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = ta
        
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.highlighted.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.disabled.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.focused.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.backgroundImage?.withTintColor(GOS_LINK_COLOR)
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = ta
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = ta[.foregroundColor] as! UIColor
      
        
        // Ensure back button chevron is black
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ta
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
        let backButton = UIButton()
        backButton.setTitle(" Backf", for: .normal)
        backButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        backButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: GOS_FONT_NAME, size: vcLinkSize)
        //backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleBackButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black  // Set chevron color to black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navBarAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = ta
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = GOS_LINK_COLOR
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("yes")
    }
    
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let gvc = GosViewController()
        ProfileView(pvc: gvc)
    }
}

the color constant is defined in constants.swift as such:
let GOS_LINK_COLOR: UIColor = UIColor.black

As you see, I tried setting all kinds of stuff, but the back chevron is still blue. I want it to be black. What am I missing. Haters, please accummulate your hatred. Helpers, by all means, please advise how to fix this thingie. Thanks to both parties :)

please answer, what is GosViewController?, why you have added this line addChild(hostingController), why lot of update code in view init methods? for testing?

@Immanuel GosViewController is not important, it is a delegate for some other things related to other libraries (not related to this issue). Yes, I put a lot of code in init, while trying to change the color of the back chevron. Hence my original question, how can I change it to black?

what is the order of views?. HomeView -> ProfileView.
what is the point of HomeVC

Point of HomeVC, is that it is a container for SwiftUI Views. It wraps  the HomeView using hosting controller. HomeView in turn contains other three SwiftUI Views (ProfileView, Latest....etc....). HomeVC is one of 4-5 tabs in the app, which are not relevant now.

please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui
