# SwiftUI: Dismiss View Within macOS NavigationView

Tags: swift, macos, navigation, swiftui

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279591) (on an iOS topic), the following code can be used to make a SwiftUI `View` dismiss itself:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
// ...
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

However, this approach doesn't work for a native (not Catalyst) macOS `NavigationView` setup (such as the below), where the selected view is displayed alongside the `List`.

Ideally, when any of these sub-views use the above, the list would go back to having nothing selected (like when it first launched); however, the dismiss function appears to do nothing: the view remains exactly the same.

Is this a bug, or expected macOS behaviour?

Is there another approach that can be used instead?

```
struct HelpView: View {

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    AboutAppView()
                ) {
                    Text("About this App")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    Text("Here’s a User Guide")
                ) {
                    Text("User Guide")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AboutAppView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.dismissSelf()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss Me!")
        }
    }

    private func dismissSelf() {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

FYI: The real intent is for less direct scenarios (such as triggering from an `Alert` upon completion of a task); the button setup here is just for simplicity.

Comment: Referred topic was for iOS, just in case.

Comment: Yeah, noted, thank you. Hopefully most SwiftUI functionality works across both, but this appears not to be one of those situations. I think I saw comments suggesting it doesn’t work for iPadOS split view either, but I’m not certain on that first hand.

Comment: I’ve also made that OS variance explicit in the question now.

Comment: @TheNeil any Idea, how to solve this in MacOS in the meantime?

Comment: Hi @mica. Unfortunately, no. Haven't seen any answer come in for this one. Honestly, I'm mostly working around it by using more conditional views and steering away from navigation views, but that's far from ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is simple. Do not use Navigation View where you need to dismiss the view.

Check the example given by Apple https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app

If you need dismissable view, there is 2 way.

1. Create a new modal window [(This is more complicated)](https://onmyway133.github.io/blog/How-to-present-NSWindow-modally/)
2. Use sheet.

Following is implimenation fo sheet in macOS with SwiftUI

```
struct HelpView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination:
                    VStack {
                        Button("About"){ self.showModal.toggle() }
                        Text("Here’s a User Guide")
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("User Guide")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            AboutAppView(showModal: self.$showModal)
        }
    }
}

struct AboutAppView: View {
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showModal.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss Me!")
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a 3rd option to use ZStack to create a Modal Card in RootView and change opacity to show and hide with dynamic data.