# Wrapped SwiftUI View popping itself

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I have a SwiftUI View wrapped in a UIHostingController that's then pushed onto the nav stack from a UIViewController.

It's pushed in this way:

```
let controller = TransactionDetailsHostingController(transactionRecord: record)
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

I want a custom back button that will pop the view from the navstack and I tried the technique used here and elsewhere: [SwiftUI - Is there a popViewController equivalent in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492965/swiftui-is-there-a-popviewcontroller-equivalent-in-swiftui)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The wrapped view doesn't pop from the navstack. I need a solution that works on iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for pop to view the controller.

1. Use closure. Create closure inside the SwiftUI view and call from the controller.
   Here is the demo.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var onBack: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            onBack()
        }, label: {
            Text("Go to back")
        })
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func onNavigation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView(onBack: {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }))
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

2. Find the top most controller and pop. You can find top controller from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301729/14733292)

And then use like this

```
UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```